# Local Volatility calculation in Python

Tags: python, local-volatility, finite-difference-method

I am trying to price Local Volatility in Python using Dupire (Finite Difference Method).

I have following set of information

Spot: 770.05, Strike: 850, Type: 'C', rfr: 0.0066, time to maturity = 25/365 days, IV: 0.19468.

In order to solve using FDM we need to find

[image]

[image]

I have used following code in python, can you please let me know what is missing here.

deltat = 0.00071
delta = 1.5

```
dc_by_dt = ((bsm_price('c',0.1946811865981668,770.05,850,0.0066,25.55/365)+deltat,0)) -(bsm_price('c',0.1946811865981668,770.05,850,0.0066,deltat-(25.55/365),0))) / (2 * delta)

dc2_by_dk2 = ((bsm_price('c',0.1946811865981668,770.05,(850-delta),0.0066,25.55/365,0)) - 2 * (bsm_price('c',0.1946811865981668,770.05,850,0.0066,25.55/365,0)) + (bsm_price('c',0.1946811865981668,770.05,(850 + delta),0.0066,25.55/365,0))) / (delta*delta)

local = np.sqrt((dc_by_dt)/(0.5*(850*850)*dc2_by_dk2))
```

Comment: From which library do you get `bsm_price`?

Comment: @Sanjay, Thanks for your reply. bsm_price is function I have defined to price options using black scholes formula. In that case you need scipy and numpy. But, my real concern is about local volatility using dupire formula can you please help me with any real life example where you have worked on to get local volatility based on Implied Volatility as an input. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not written in Python, but in R. If you have experience with R this real life example posted on an underground quant blog has step by step what you may be looking for: (Scroll down to conclusion)

https://quantipy.wordpress.com/2017/08/21/implementation-of-dupires-formula-for-local-volatilities/

(I do not take credit for this persons work), but it's intuition has helped me greatly when I was tackling a similar volatility model problem.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Vincent, Thanks for your reply, I did look at his work and I really appreciate that he has put lots of effort to do that. I am more keen to do it in python so I guess I need to figure out my own way.

Answer (score 0):

By having constant implied volatility as an input you defeat the purpose of using local vol plus think about your butterfly value.  I will venture to say your local vol may blow up.

A better way is to compute local variance of the actual implied vol surface.